# Kendo angular detail grid layout issue

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

It seems the kendo angular 2 detail grid layout breaks very easily while zooming in chrome. Does setting width of columns has anything to do with this?

Reproducible here [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/l1JgHqc56S1J3Fa4sVvo?p=preview)

```
<kendo-grid
          [data]="view | async"
          [pageSize]="5"
          [skip]="skip"
          [pageable]="true"
          [scrollable]="'none'"
          (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
        >
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="120">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="220">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="220">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="120">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="220">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" format="{0:c}">
      </kendo-grid-column>
      </kendo-grid>
```

Either set the resolution to 1048 x 768. Or zoom in 'in chrome'
Grid layout breaks (no horizontal scrollbars to navigate)

Comment: You can use [scrollable] ="scrollable" or "virtual" property and you can also set proper height to your kendo grid so if you change your resolution then your layout will not break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the width for the Product Name and the Unit Price columns and set the scrollable property to "scrollable" in the kendogrid.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the "scrollable" property of the Grid component can be set to one of three modes - 'scrollable', 'none', and 'virtual':

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-scrollable

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ScrollMode/

The default is 'scrollable', so if the property is omitted in the Grid markup, the result will be the same as setting it to 'scrollable'.

Comment: The default seems to be none. Do you have a reference stating 'scrollable' is the default